# Friday Night Funkin' error

Tags: 18.04

I'm having some trouble when trying to run the Friday Night Funkin' executable.

This error happens when I try to run the Funkin file.

[image: This error happens when I try to run the Funkin file.]

Comment: please don't provide pictures of text... I can't copy & paste detail from a picture; so you can explore the libraries yourself and match with your stated release.

Comment: By posting a picture of text, you make it impossible for potential helpers on phones, or text terminals. to see your text. You make it impossible for any of us to make a local copy for investigation. Rather, [Edit] your Question, copy and paste the text into your Question, select it and use the `{}` formatting tool.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that libc6 on 18.04 LTS has version 2.27. The game needs 2.29, we can adjust this by the hack below:

```
# download newer libc6 from 20.04 LTS repository
cd /tmp
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb
dpkg -x libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb /tmp/l

# copy newer library to game folder
cp /tmp/l/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.so ~/Desktop/friday/
cp /tmp/l/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 ~/Desktop/friday/

# set environment variable and play
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/Desktop/friday

cd ~/Desktop/friday
./Funkin
```

Enjoy!